# Деплой на Jelastic

Tags: maven, java

Пытаюсь настроить деплой аппликейшина на джеластик с помощью маван плагина, выдает такую ошибку

Plugin com.jelastic:jelastic-maven-plugin:1.7-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.jelastic:jelastic-maven-plugin:jar:1.7-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.jelastic:jelastic-maven-plugin:pom:1.7-SNAPSHOT in https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of sonatype-oss-public has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

Правильно понимаю, что не доступна одна из транзитивных зависимостей?
Сталкиваюсь первый раз, решил уточнить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну да, не разрешил зависимости com.jelastic:jelastic-maven-plugin:1.7-SNAPSHOT или его самого не нашёл.
Может вам не нужен SNAPSHOT, попробуйте так:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.jelastic</groupId>
    <artifactId>jelastic-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    ....
</plugin>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, это решило проблему!

Comment: @Печенька Молоке если ответ вам нравится поднимите репутацию нажатием на иконку слева от ответа, а если ответ принят нажмите на галочку там же - рядом. У вас всего 20% ответов приняты - это как бы маловато. Не исключаю, что в следующий раз вам никто не ответит.

Comment: Сделал. 
Получил ответ и убежал. Не надо так)